Flatpak install freezes when downloading resource. Can I find source URL to download file manually from browser?
I am trying to update the Gnome Web (org.gnome.Epiphany) flatpak, on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (on WSL2). One specific resource, "org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264" always freezes when downloading. My internet connection is fine, and I can download other files/resources from Flathub fine, just not this one:
user@device:~$ sudo flatpak update org.gnome.Epiphany
[sudo] password for user:
Looking for updates…
Required runtime for org.gnome.Epiphany/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/46) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [Y/n]: y

        ID                                        Branch         Op        Remote         Download
 1. [—] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264         2.4.1          i         flathub            1.0 kB / 976.5 kB
 2. [ ] org.gnome.Platform.Locale                 46             i         flathub        < 367.4 MB
 3. [ ] org.gnome.Platform                        46             i         flathub        < 346.3 MB
 4. [ ] org.gnome.Epiphany                        stable         u         flathub         < 11.6 MB

Installing 1/4… █▌                     8%

I have tried uninstalling, force-reinstalling, running flatpak repair, rebooting the system, switching wifi networks, using a VPN, everything I can think of.
Is there any way I can find, either from the flatpak cli or somewhere online, the specific version of "org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264" it's trying to download and what URL it is being served from? I think I would be able to download it in a browser or using curl, or find a mirror repo or something, and manually install it from the file, but I don't know how to find that information.
(Alternatively, if I found or compiled an up-to-date .flatpak file for Gnome Web to do a manual offline install, would that include these other runtime packages bundled in it?)
